# How to keep an image in a UIImageView when switching between multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, image

I'm trying to write an extremely basic Xcode (ver. 5) project application for the iPhone5 that loads an image from the photo library into an `UIImageView` in the start up `UIViewController` and keeps that image in the `UIImageView` (or returns it) when switching between other view controller panels. The problem I am having is that when I return from other `UIViewController` windows to the main view controller with my `UIImageView`, the loaded image that was previously displayed is gone and I end up having to reload it into the `UIImageView`. How can I make this behave where the image remains in the `UIImageView` after I return from other `UIViewController` windows?

Implementation File...

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    modBuffer = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = modBuffer;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImage* modBuffer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Where did you allocate your self.imageView?

Comment: you have to store this image and then display this image from that stored path in to imageView.

Comment: Made code edits. I apparently had previously copied wrong code.

Comment: How are you returning to ViewController after going to another view controller?

Comment: I have two other buttons which have modal actions to switch between the two. Option under "Triggered Segues" ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make property for `UIImage (nonatomic,retain)` and then u should try to do it.

Comment: This is not necessary. The image is in an image view, and that image view keeps a strong pointer to its image.

Comment: I tried (nonatomic, retain) and it didn't work. I encountered the same issue.